# Relative Path returns 404

Tags: html

I have a strange problem with a simple relative path

the browser has to load some SWF files.

```
../../en2/files/fl.swf
```

and it's OK, I see it.

But when I copied that file one level above

```
../../../en2/files/fl.swf
```

then I get the 404 error. Why ?

### edit

that files are loaded by the `swfobject.embedSWF()` function (as the variable)

here's what firebug outputs:

```
/Scripts/m_f/../../en45/files/f_l6.swf
```

OK

but

```
/Scripts/m_f/../../../en45/files/f_l6.swf
```

gives me 404 (flash #2032) All files exists in that paths. **It seems that it can't go above that the root folder ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you copied the file one level above, you should use:

```
../en2/files/fl.swf
```

If you copied the file one level nested beneath your home directory, then you should use:

```
../../../en2/files/fl.swf
```